# Unicode error with \u0000 on COPY of large JSON file into Postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.4, json, regex, unicode

I'm using Postgres 9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have a 30GB JSON file that I'm trying to COPY into Postgres.

But I keep getting the following error:

```
COPY <table>(comment_jsonb) FROM '<json file>' WITH (format csv, quote e'\x01', delimiter e'\x02', escape e'\x01');
ERROR:  unsupported Unicode escape sequence
DETAIL:  \u0000 cannot be converted to text.
```

I tried searching for the offending Unicode string to remove it, but because it's \u0000, which is NULL, I can't seem to get a regex to work. And when I print it into console, I have no idea where the NULL is, because (at least my guess is) it seems to print as nothing (though I have no idea what it is actually doing).

Is there a way to skip these errors?

Alternatively, how could I replace any instances of that Unicode in my JSON file?

Comment: The NUL character can only be present in a JSON string as the escape sequence `\u0000`. You should have no trouble searching for that string; you may only need to escape the backslash, often by doubling it. Alternatively (and because this is a database site), you could use the `json` column type. Its performance is less good than `jsonb`, but it is fine with NUL.

Answer (score 5):

In a (perhaps) similar case I had been confronted with \u0000 in a string I needed to process as JSON. The follow replace worked for me:

```
regexp_replace(stringWithNull, '\\u0000', '', 'g')
```

Hope this helps.